# OnClick event in html datepicker without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using Html, I want to make my max date dependent on another date

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5">Arrival Date: <input class="form-control" type="date" min="<?php echo $datetoday?>" name="arrival" required></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5">Departure Date: <input class="form-control" type="date" name="depart" required></div>
</div>
```

I want to make the min of departure date is value of arrival date, is there anything I can do without using jQuery?

Comment: NO! you can't do this as html is static you need either js or do it serverside at php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set eg. `max="2019-12-31"` to limit date range. This can be done on the backend where you create your HTML. If this is dynamic (ie. the user selects an arrival date and you want to limit the departure date) you need Javascript/jQuery.